# jQuery won't select XML elements in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, xslt

**Update: Question edited to add more information.**

My app directly views XML data in a browser -- after some light client-side XSLT processing that we can assume here is just the identity transform inside a thin HTML wrapper.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match ="/">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

With jQuery 1.8.3, this

```
$("*[target]").click(function (event) {
    alert("click");
});
```

will (or should) select elements that have a @target attribute.

This works fine in IE and Chrome, but in Firefox jQuery won't select anything unless I change the XSLT output to "html", which messes up other things.

What is the correct way, in Firefox, to get jQuery to select non-HTML, XML elements or -- which might be saying the same thing a different way -- to get jQuery to select custom HTML elements?

**Update: Found source of problem.** The selectors do not select because they are inside $(document).ready() and that does not fire for XML documents styled with XSLT (output='xml') in Firefox. Someone else with same problem: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-with-xslt-in-xhtml

I haven't found a combination of parameters and code order to get it to fire. My workaround so far is to use $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready().

**More Update** There is now a **jQuery bug report** for this, #13193. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13193

Comment: Which xml elements specifically?

Comment: do you think posting an invalid xml(xslt)-fragment and a jQuery-snippet that doesn't have any relation to the fragment is  
appropriate to get an answer?

Comment: Well, um, yeah. For those who hang out at the intersection of XSLT, XML, and jQuery, I thought it was a nicely essentialized question actually. I figured those who don't hang out there would just drive by.

Comment: Which xml elements? One is called <t-ref>. Another is <s-atts>. The point is that they are application-specific elements, what some would call "custom HTML elements".

Comment: The original XML is not part of the website DOM and therefore inaccessible to jQuery. If this isn't your problem, please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap jQuery code in

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // jQuery bindings here
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // jQuery bindings here
});
```

This will delay availability of the jQuery bindings, but they will get made

jQuery team has accepted this as a bug. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13193

Switch back to `$(document).ready` once the bug is fixed.